# Call function when call another function

Tags: python, django

I want to call some function from django view.

```
Class view(view):
    Def get(self):
        Some stuff...
        Return httpresponse


Def a():
       Some stuff
```

I want to call a() function when view is called, without calling a() in view body.
Maybe there is any decorator or something else, which helps me with it.
Something like:

```
Class view(view):
        Def get(self):
            Some stuff from view
            Return httpresponse

@call_with_view
    Def a():
           Some stuff from a

>> View()
>> some stuff from view
>> Some stuff from a
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use function a() in view() if it supposed to run with view() itself ? creating a trigger is kinda overwork when you can just call it inside another function

Comment: I want to call many functions, from different places, and I don't want call every of it in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this work is too much but You can use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) for this:

1. Create a signal when view gets called
2. Create a signal receiver to get that signal and run you function

your code will be like:

```
a_func_signal = django.dispatch.Signal()

class View:
    def get():
         a_func_signal
             a_func_signal.send()


@receiver(a_func_signal)
def a():
    some stuff
```